# How to hide Default values using Drupal Behaviour

Tags: forms, javascript, webforms

I have created a form using the web form module. In this form i have 3 field. Name, Email and Phone. I have set the default values for Name as Name , Email as E-mail and Phone as Phone (Done this using the form settings).

Now the scenario is, when the user clicks on the Name field , The default values has to go off. I tried this using jQuery but it didnt work. So i thought of using Drupal Behaviours with jQuery.

This is my code

```
(function (jQuery) { 
 Drupal.behaviors.amendor = {
    jQuery('edit-submitted-phone').focus(function() {
      alert('Chekcing the values');
      if (jQuery('edit-submitted-phone').val() == 'edit-submitted-phone'.defaultValue) {
        jQuery('edit-submitted-phone').val('');
      }
    });

    jQuery('edit-submitted-phone').blur(function() {
      alert('setting the values');
      if (!jQuery('edit-submitted-phone').val()) {
        jQuery('edit-submitted-phone').val('edit-submitted-phone'.defaultValue);
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: As behaviours can be attached more than once, you should protect against attaching your handlers multiple times by using [jQuery once](http://drupal.org/node/756722#jquery-once).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, as you're namespacing jQuery you can use the `$` instead of jQuery inside the `(function (jQuery) { ... });`

Secondly, you're not pointing to classes or ID's in your jQuery.  I'm pretty sure that `edit-submitted-phone` should be `#edit-submitted-phone` in every instance in your code.

If this doesn't work, then let me know and I'll see what else I can come up with.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I missed # in the IDs. Now its working fine for me:)

Answer (score 0):

There's a module called [Compact Forms](http://drupal.org/project/compact_forms) that does this for you.

If you still want to do it yourself, I'd suggest **against** using the `defaultValue` attribute since this can screw up the form processing if you didn't put necessary logic in the validate and submit handlers (which is more work) and it's generally not a nice way to do this imho.

Instead, since you can select any attribute with [`jQuery.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), I'd suggest creating your own custom attribute in the `hook_form_alter` and assign the default values there. And just check the current values against that attribute like so:

```
if (jQuery('#edit-submitted-phone').val() == jQuery('#edit-submitted-phone').attr('my-custom-attr')) {
  jQuery('#edit-submitted-phone').val('');
}
```

And finally as Chapabu mentioned, you're missing the vital parts of your selectors, which is the ID (`#`) or the Class (`.`) selectors just like you'd write in a CSS document.

Comment: Chapabu's reply helped me. Thanks for your reply baysaa:)